# Search and highlight text of current text in PDFKit Swift

Tags: swift, react-native, pdfkit, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

I'm working on a React Native app that displays PDFs using a custom NativeModule written in Swift. The module successfully renders PDFs from a provided file URL. But, I'm struggling with a feature to highlight specific text within the PDF.

I'm passing text to highlight, startOffset and endOffset, and Page No. from **React Native** to the **NativeModule** using the Bridge. The offsets are obtained from page.string, and due to which offsets might not always translate accurately to rectangle selection due to variations in font styles and layouts:\n
I tried the below approach by searching from various platforms, but did not helped me.

```
  @objc
  func highlightText(_ pageNumber: Int, startOffset: Int, endOffset: Int, searchText: String, changeType: String) {
      guard let page = pdfView.document?.page(at: pageNumber - 1) else {
          print("Failed to get PDF page for page \(pageNumber)")
          return
      }
    // Create a PDFSelection based on the offsets
    let startIndex = searchText.index(searchText.startIndex, offsetBy: startOffset)
    let endIndex = searchText.index(searchText.startIndex, offsetBy: endOffset)
    let range = NSRange(startIndex..<endIndex, in: searchText)
    let selection = page.selection(for: range)!
    
    // Get the bounding box of the selection
    let boundingBox = selection.bounds(for: page)
    
    // Create a highlight annotation and add it to the page
    let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: boundingBox, forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
    highlight.color = UIColor.yellow.withAlphaComponent(0.5) // Adjust highlight color and opacity
    page.addAnnotation(highlight)
  }
```

**I tried the below approaches:**

1. Tried something like **document.findString**, but it takes **time** and **memory**, and sometimes kill the App.
2. Tried getting **CGRect** from **offsets**, but can't get these also.

I want a solution, where I just wanted to highlight the text on the Page Number.